# Кнопка "Поделиться" в Instagram

Tags: php, javascript, html, instagram

Возможна ли реализация кнопки `Поделиться` в Instagram? Например, прикрепляешь кнопку к статье и делишься в Instagram `intro`-картинкой из этой статьи. Везде, где ни читал, склоняются к обратному.

Comment: они же апишку порезали и дают доступ в ручном режиме. слишком много лайк ботов было. да и раньше вроде постить можно было только через приложение. к примеру всякие фильтры итп просто сохраняют картинку в телефон, а постишь уже через оф апп

Comment: Через веб почти нереально. Можно проснифать офф.клиент инстаграмма и отследить метод апи для публикации фотографии, однако токен, который необходим для публикации - генерится только в официальном клиенте.

Comment: Спасибо. Примерно таких ответов и ждал.